# How to use custom checked or ticked event of radiogroup in Extjs 4

Tags: extjs

I want to call change event only when we checked radio button but the change event are also calling when we set value...like this.

```
Ext.getCmp('2007').setValue({ '2007': 'NoAccess' });
```

Anyone can tell me how can we use custom checked event or any other event so we will call the change event only on **checked(click)** radio button.

> I'm using Ext.Version 4.2.1.

Here is my code:-

```
                 {
                    xtype: 'radiogroup',
                    fieldLabel: '&nbsp;&nbsp;Admin Notes',
                    labelStyle: 'font-size: 12px;color:#3399CC;',
                    margin: '0 0 0 3',
                    defaultType: 'radio',
                    id: '2007', 
                    name: '2007',
                    defaults: {
                        flex: 1
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            boxLabel: 'Read and Update',
                            inputValue: 'ReadUpdate',
                            name: '2007'
                        }, {
                            boxLabel: 'Read Only',
                            margin: '0 0 0 20',
                            inputValue: 'ReadOnly',
                            name: '2007'
                        }, {
                            boxLabel: 'No Access',
                            inputValue: 'NoAccess',
                            name: '2007'
                        }
                    ],


                    listeners: {
                        change: function() {

                          alert("True");

                        },
```

Comment: Where exactly are you doing Ext.getCmp('2007').setValue({ '2007': 'NoAccess' }); ?

Comment: When form load then we set that value, so in this time the change event also calling.
I want the change event should call only when click on checked radio button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before to use [`setValue()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup-method-setValue) first you need to use following two methods of [`RadioGroup`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup).

**1)**. [`suspendEvent`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup-method-suspendEvent) or [`suspendEvents`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup-method-suspendEvents) to `Suspends the firing of particular or all events`.

**2).** `radiogroup.setValue({name:'value'})` the radio with corresponding name and value will be set.

**3).** [`resumeEvent`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup-method-resumeEvent) or [`resumeEvents`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup-method-resumeEvents) to resumes firing of the named event or all events.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2b36)**, I have created a demo using `radiogroup`. I hope it will help you to achieve your requirement.

**Code Snippet**

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'RadioGroup example with change event call when dyanmic value set.',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        fieldLabel: 'Admin Notes',
        defaultType: 'radio',
        id: '2007',
        defaults: {
            name: '2007'
        },
        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'Read and Update',
            inputValue: 'ReadUpdate'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Read Only',
            margin: '0 0 0 20',
            inputValue: 'ReadOnly'
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'No Access',
            inputValue: 'NoAccess'
        }],
        listeners: {
            change: function (cmp, newValue) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Checked value is :- ' + newValue['2007']);
            }
        }
    }],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function () {
            var rb = Ext.getCmp('2007');
            rb.suspendEvents();
            rb.setValue({
                '2007': 'NoAccess'
            });
            rb.resumeEvents();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much !